# C++: Migrating dll from VS 2008 to VS 2010: error C2678

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm migrating the code of an dll, developed with C++, from Visual Studio version 2008 to 2010.
I'm facing this error below which is related to the 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring'.

Error C2678: binary operator '!=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'c_allocator<_Ty>'  (or there is no acceptable conversion).

The error occurs with the line 'class c_allocator: public std::_Allocator_base<_Ty>{'.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Synchro.h"
template<class _Ty>
class c_allocator: public std::_Allocator_base<_Ty>{
public:
typedef _Allocator_base<_Ty> _Mybase;
typedef typename _Mybase::value_type value_type;
typedef value_type _FARQ *pointer;
typedef value_type _FARQ& reference;
typedef const value_type _FARQ *const_pointer;
typedef const value_type _FARQ& const_reference;
typedef _SIZT size_type;
typedef _PDFT difference_type;

template<class _Other>struct rebind{
    typedef c_allocator<_Other> other;
};

pointer address(reference _Val) const {
    return (&_Val);
}

const_pointer address(const_reference _Val) const {
    return (&_Val);
}

c_allocator() _THROW0() {
}

c_allocator(const c_allocator<_Ty>&) _THROW0() {
}

template<class _Other>c_allocator(const c_allocator<_Other>&) _THROW0() {
}

template<class _Other>c_allocator<_Ty>& operator=(const c_allocator<_Other>&) {
    return (*this);
}

void deallocate(pointer _Ptr, size_type) {
    CustomAlloc::LinearAllocHolder<1>::alloc.freemem(_Ptr);
}

pointer allocate(size_type _Count) {
    return (pointer)CustomAlloc::LinearAllocHolder<1>::alloc.getmem(_Count*sizeof(value_type));
}

pointer allocate(size_type _Count, const void _FARQ *) {
    return (allocate(_Count));
}

void construct(pointer _Ptr, const _Ty& _Val) {
    std::_Construct(_Ptr, _Val);
}

void destroy(pointer _Ptr) {    
    std::_Destroy(_Ptr);
}

_SIZT max_size() const _THROW0() {
    _SIZT _Count = (_SIZT)(-1) / sizeof (_Ty);
    return (0 < _Count ? _Count : 1);
}
   };
```

Any hint much appreciated - 
thanks in advance - 
surplus

Comment: You are relying on internal undocumented implementation details. You are not supposed to use `_Allocator_base` directly in your program. In any case, all it gives you is a `value_type` typedef - you could just as well define that yourself.

Comment: Your class does not meet [allocator requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator), by not supporting `!=` comparison, among other things. That's the immediate cause of the problem.

Comment: I fixed all my stuff, but now XLL is crashing MSExcel.
Igor, may I write you a PM because of special support pls?

Regards
surplus